A $4\times 4$ linear system with four parameters
Consider the following linear system
$$\begin{cases}
    x + y + z + t = 1,\\
    ax + by + cz + dt = 1,\\
    a^2x + b^2y + c^2z + d^2t = 1,\\
    a^3x + b^3y + c^3z + d^3t = 1\end{cases}$$
What is the best way to attack such linear systems with so many parameters? I am not just asking the solution of a homework and I have done a lot of things (which I can share should somebody ask them).
For instance I have found that if $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ are distinct the system has a unique solution, namely:
\begin{align*}
x&=-\frac{(b-1)(c-1)(d-1)}{(a-b)(a-c)(a-d)}\\
 y&=\frac{(a-1)(c-1)(d-1)}{(a-b)(b-c)(b-d)} \\
 z&= -\frac{(a-1)(b-1)(d-1)}{(a-c)(b-c)(c-d)}\\
 t&=\frac{(a-1)(b-1)(c-1)}{(a-d)(b-d)(c-d)}
\end{align*}
Also when dealing with different cases and sub-cases a common pattern appears. Namely that one of $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ should be equal to 1 for the system to be consistent (with infinite number of solutions; with one, two or three degrees of freedom). But there are so many cases and subcases to consider and I think that I repeat myself.
I have worked with Gauss-Jordan elimination. Should I best consider the Gauss elimination? Or should I give up altogether the Gauss approach and consider instead Cramer's Method?
Is another approach better suitable?
As a side question: can softwares like Mathematica or Matlab be used to treat the different cases and subcases? (and not just the unique solution case with distinct values of the parameters)?
Thank you very much for any help.
Edit:
Can I consider the following cases (and the arising subcases)

All four parameters are distinct ($a \neq b \neq c \neq d$).

Two parameters are equal, and the other two are distinct ($a = b \neq c \neq d$).


3.Three parameters are equal, and the last one is distinct ($a = b = c \neq d$).

All parameters are equal ($a = b = c = d$).

and say that any other case is equivalent to one of these four, up to permutations?

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix.

@QiaochuYuan. I know about the Vandermonde matrix. So you are suggesting to treat the problem with the Cramer Method?

The best way is to write it as a matrix equation $Ax=b$. By Vandermonde, the matrix $A$ is invertible for distinct $a,b,c,d$ and we know the inverse, so that $x=A^{-1}b$ is the unique solution. This has been asked before here.

@DietrichBurde. As I explained I have already treated  the distinct parameters scenario. I want to treat the subcases that arise.

@DietrichBurde Can I consider the following four subcases, namely \begin{enumerate}
\item All four parameters are distinct ((a \neq b \neq c \neq d)).
\item Two parameters are equal, and the other two are distinct ((a = b \neq c \neq d)).
\item Three parameters are equal, and the last one is distinct ((a = b = c \neq d)).
\item All parameters are equal ((a = b = c = d)).
\end{enumerate}
and say that any other case is equivalent to one of these four, up to permutations.
